# template constant type conversion operator not working under linux (gcc)

Tags: c++, templates, types, constants, type-conversion

Consider the following program:

```
#include <iostream>

template<int s>
class Pack
{
public:
    Pack(){}
    char data[s];
    template<typename X> operator X&(){ return *reinterpret_cast<X*>(data); }
    template<typename X> operator X const&()const{ return *reinterpret_cast<const X*>(data); }
};

int main()
{
    const Pack<8> p;
    const double d(p);
    std::cout<<d<<std::endl;
}
```

It compiles fine under Windows.
Under linux I get:

```
test.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cc:17: error: passing ‘const Pack<8>’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘Pack<s>::operator X&() [with X = double, int s = 8]’ discards qualifiers
```

Why? Why is it not taking the const type conversion operator? How can I fix this and still have the convenient templated type conversion operator (in const and not const version).
Thanks!

Comment: I'm getting a different error with GCC (and Comeau). It doesn't find any conversion function. Probably because it is looking for a conversion function such as `operator double()` and doesn't find a suitable one (because the provided ones also have a reference). - If it's a good idea in the first place, why not use a named member function?

Comment: @UncleBens, you are correct, see below.

Comment: I do not want to use the operator double(), because the Pack class should be convertible to any type. The example I posted is stripped down to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the C++03 Standard, that code is ill-formed because template argument deduction will not be able to deduce `X&` or `X const&` against `const double`.

C++03 missed to state that the reference is stripped off from the return type of the conversion function prior to deduction, so you can never get a match in your case. For C++0x, [this will be fixed](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#322) and is included in the latest working paper, so it may compile with some compilers that include the fix retroactively.

*Your* code actually has a different problem: GCC *does* implement that defect report resolution, and therefor compares `double` (it strips off cv-qualifiers prior to deduction!) against `X` and against `X const`. Only `X` matches and so only that first conversion function is the single candidate in a call with a `const Pack<8>` argument - that's why GCC complains about the missing `const` on the conversion function. If you try the following code it would work

```
// can't strip cv-qualifiers off "double const&" - there are no top-level 
// cv qualifiers present here!
double const &d(p);
```

Comment: Why is the const qualifier stripped from `double`?  An why does it match if I add `operator double const&()const`?  You are probably right, but I don't understand yet...

Comment: @Sven because the `const` has no meaning. The value is copied from the return of the conversion function anyway. The `const` has only a meaning if it's buried in a pointer or a reference. It matches when you do `operator double const&` because it then doesn't need template argument deduction. The crux here only is template argument deduction: *That* yields the candidate functions overload which resolution considers when dealing with templates. If you write `operator double const&` then *you* supply the candidate function explicitly, and here it is a candidate function that can be called.

Comment: Try with a simplier example: `template<typename T> void f(T*);` if you call it with `f(0)` it won't work because template argument deduction of `T*` against `int` fails. But if you declare a `void f(char*);` and then calling `f(0)` it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth explanation.  I see in what way `const` doesn't have a meaning, but I don't understand why the compiler drops it.  In this case it *would* make a difference, right?  So in this case, it *has* a meaning.  Well, I guess that's what is fixed in C++0x.

Comment: Regarding my second question:  I know the difference between template argument deduction and function argument type matching.  I just did not understans why `const` is dropped in one case but not in the other.